# Gulp simple vendor build

Tags: gulp

I have downloaded the extension boilerplate 
https://github.com/EmailThis/extension-boilerplate/blob/master/manifest.json

I want to include jquery on the build process by using gulp I do

```
const files = [
'jquery-3.1.1.min.js'
];
let vendorTasks = files.map( file => {
return browserify({
  entries: 'src/scripts/vendor/' + file,
  debug: true
})
.bundle()
.pipe(source(file))
.pipe(buffer())
.pipe(gulp.dest(`build/${target}/scripts/vendor`));
```

});

This copies the file to dest but it transforms it in some way and then I get an error $ is not defined. How can I use gulp to copy the file to the destination folder without change it ?